# React TypeScript build project on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

So i'm working on a project that use React TypeScript.

the `package.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ///...
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     ///...
    "@types/react": "16.8.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "esnext"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

With just a `npm install; npm start`, it builds and compile on Windows normally, and runs using TSC @3.5.2. For Linux(Ubuntu) it run on TSC @3.7.5 and it gets syntax errors and fail to compile, even though on TSC @3.5.2 i get the same results like :

```
(80,67): Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try two things:

1. First, remove the `node_modules` folder on both of your builds and try a fresh `npm install` followed by an `npm start`
2. If that doesn't work, also try removing the `^`s from your `devDependencies`/`dependencies`, and repeat #1. My theory is that the Linux version of the code is receiving a different version of TypeScript (or some `@types`) when you `npm install`.

Let me know if these work!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i already tried this one and still not working !

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the answer, the problem was that the Ubuntu Linux package for NodeJs was not updated to the last version, so you get an old version when you compare on the one you download from Node website, so i just downloaded the .tar on their website and just installed manually !